# How do I produce a time series plot using a tsibble object?

Tags: r, time-series, ggplot2

I am having difficulty producing a time series plot with a tsibble object as an input.

I am using the following code:

```
library(Ecdat)
library(tsibble)
library(ggplot2)
library(fable)
library(fabletools)
library(feasts)
inflation <- as.numeric(Mishkin[, 1])
data_ts <- ts(inflation,start=c(1950,2), frequency = 12)
data_tsbl <- as_tsibble(data_ts)

gg <- data_tsbl %>% ggplot2::autoplot(vars(value),xlab = "Month")
gg
```

I get an error: Ignoring unknown parameters: xlab.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoplot()` creates a ggplot object, and you specify the `xlab` after that:

```
data_tsbl %>% ggplot2::autoplot(vars(value))+xlab("Month")
```

[image]